# ¿Por qué se agrega una fila vacia en mi base de datos?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Estoy aprendiendo a como usar la base de datos, estoy usando Xampp, cuestión que no tengo ningún código repetido y al enviar los datos. La base de datos me los toma y los registra (hasta aquí todo bien) pero genera después una fila vacía (osea sin datos), le pregunté a mi profesor y no supo solucionarme el problema, por lo tanto vengo a pedir ayuda aquí!

Estoy trabajando en php, este es el código de la página principal del formulario:

```
<section class="Seccion" id="Email">
    <h1>Consulta gratis</h1>
    <p>Pon tu email y serás contactado lo antes posible</p>
    <form action="contacto.php" method="POST" >
        <input type="text" placeholder = "Nombre y Apellido" name="Nombre" id="Nombre">
        <input type="email" placeholder = "Email" name="Correo" id="Correo">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="Enviar">
    </form>
</section>
```

Y este es el código del contacto.php, donde me conecto a la base de datos y envio los datos:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "php_database_contact";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if($link === false){
die ("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Nombre']);
$correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Correo']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO contactos(id, nombre, email) VALUES (null, '$nombre','$correo')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Se añadio";
}
else{
    echo "ERROR, no se añadió" . mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

Al enviar los datos, en el navegador, me aparece "Se añadió", ya que puse esa función para saber si agrega a la BD o tira un error, y al fijarme en la base de datos pasa esto.  (Ingresé dos veces datos para que vean que siempre me agrega una fila vacia, adjunto foto) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: verifica si tus variables $nombre y $correo tienen valores

Comment: tienes un `null` en `INSERT INTO contactos(id, nombre, email) VALUES (null, '$nombre','$correo')` si el id de la tabla es autoincremental no hace falta enviar el id, cambia esa consulta por `INSERT INTO contactos(nombre, email) VALUES ('$nombre','$correo')"`

Comment: Ejecuta un `INSERT INTO ` directamente en la base de datos a ver si también agrega una fila adicional en blanco. Si es así, entonces es posible que haya un `TRIGGER` programado que agregue una fila vacía después de cada inserción. En el código PHP no se ve repetición de la consulta, a no ser que en las dos ocasiones le hayas dado click al botón `Enviar` del formulario **dos veces**.

Comment: Me fijé el tema de las variables y no es eso. Tampoco lo de sacar el id de la sentencia del INSERT INTO, me sigue pasando el mismo problema.
Y la tercera respuesta que me dijo de hacer un INSERT INTO desde la base de datos, funcionó. No creó ninguna fila vacía después, pero desde el código lo sigue haciendo